# Tap Gesture on UILabel not firing above text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a strange issue at the moment.  I create a UILabel and set a tap gesture to it.  It only fires when I tap on the space above the text..  When I tap on the text in the label, the gesture never fires.

```
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((sideMenuViewWidth - sideMenuViewWidth * 0.9) / 2, hPos, largestLabelWidth * 1.2, 30)];
    lbl.text = content.itemName;
    [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-bold" size:18]];
    lbl.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:targetViewController action:content.itemTapHandler];
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [lbl addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Does anything look incorrect in my block of code?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks fine to me. I've just tried your code (slightly modified: changed the frame, the background color and the gesture recognizer's target/selector), and it worked. At first I thought, that your frame might be too small, but UILabel clips its content to bounds, so you would've noticed.

Comment: Thanks for checking :) it turns out my subview index was incorrect and I had another subview above it.  Fixed it by setting moving label to top.

Comment: Oh, I see :) Glad, that you solved your issue :) You can leave an answer yourself and accept it. Or I don't know. It's just better to indicate for other users somehow, that the problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that the subview index was incorrect.  There was another subview above it which was intercepting the tap.  This was fixed using the following snippet:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:lbl];
```